# How to get layer depth of an image inside a powerpoint presentation using pptx to check if it's visible?

Tags: python, xml, powerpoint, python-pptx

I'm using pptx to run quality checks on some powerpoint presentations. I need to check if an image is visible: it must not be covered by another one on top of it. I understand that pptx has the depth value for Charts, but i can't find the same property for shapes/images.

Comment: I think you'd have to use the boundaries of the shapes - which are both gettable and settable - to work out if there were overlap. One caution: I think it's possible for eg text to escape the bounds of the shape.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but I think it would not give me information about which overlapping image is on top of the other

Comment: In VBA I would check both for the overlap and for the zOrder value (i.e. the index), I guess the same can be made under Python. As for the text overflowing, iI would check if the automatic resizing and the wrapping are on.

Comment: Re text outside the bounds of the shape: you can check the textrange's BoundingBox properties to determine the actual size of the text (assuming your PPT library supports it)

Comment: I don't think python-pptx will give you the z order. But maybe the sequence of the shapes or underlying XML would. And python-pptx doesn't know if the text actually escapes or not. (Yes, it says whether it should be allowed to - but I'm not sure even that is watertight.)

Comment: @MartinPacker yes looks like the sequence of the shapes follows the z-order: "Sequence of shapes appearing on a slide. The first shape in the sequence is the backmost in z-order and the last shape is topmost"